# Multiple Layers of Deep Linking in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, partials, angularjs, deep-linking, layered-navigation

I am attempting to place multiple controllers within my template partials with AngularJS- The problem I am encountering is that of the first layer, direct-linking to these sub-controllers and their related snippets.

An example would be a management page for user accounts, say I am on a user-list and wanted to change a user from the list's password, I click on their change-password button, and want to redirect the user to `#/ManageUsers/ChangePassword/?UserID=<uid here>` rather than `#/ManageUsers_ChangePassword/` or similar, but the Angular documentation (Or lack thereof) on the subject suggests that this is impossible, or not 'The Angular Way'...

Being that my team wants to keep these separate controllers as partials, is there a non-hacky way to do this with Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not direct to `#/ManageUsers/ChangePassword/:UserID` ? You can get the UserID from $routeParams. See an example on the [$route](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route) page.

You can even create routes like `#/ManageUsers/:OrganizationID/:SectorId/:UserID/ChangePassword/Confirmation` that will be used by the url `#/ManageUsers/10/2/32/ChangePassword/Confirmation`

Comment: Does such a method allow the controller for ManageUsers to remain a parent of ChangePassword's controller? What I mean is, does a separate `ng-view` inside the controller for ManageUsers then load the 'ChangePassword' view/controller?

Comment: The ChangePassword controller really need to be a child of ManageUsers? It really can't work alone?

Comment: It would make it a lot easier to keep it a child, yes- A way I can see that would make this system doable in angular would be to allow an interface behaving similar to the current routeProvider even though it is encapsulated by a parent scope, but I don't think they have it quite THAT modular...

Comment: Accepted due to this being the best possible answer with the current Angular framework's core structure for routing.

Answer (score 2):

There has been recently published a blog post about one possible way of solving deep linking with AngularJS. It has a parent/child style of implementation where parent sections do not need to be updated if you need to change only contents of the child, which makes it pretty neat.

It's here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2441-Nested-Views-Routing-And-Deep-Linking-With-AngularJS.htm