# AngularJS, Deeplinking within a view

Tags: angularjs, deep-linking

**Objective**

I am currently building my first web application with AngularJS. I need to know the correct way to deeplink to content within a view.

http://signalreview.2mellow.com/ this is the current build.

**Description of problem**

For example, You can search for mcdonalds, spokane, When this happens I want the address bar to reflect the search that was just done such as #/search/mcdonalds%20spokane so that a user can link a search to someone else. I understand how I can get the data out and initiate the search. I just don't understand how I should be utilizing Angular JS to accomplish the goal.

From my research I have determined that nested views is not a good idea.

Also I have plans to have it so that if you click a map marker for a place that has been reviewed (stored locally in the db) It would put the id in the address bar so that location could then be linked to someone else or you could bookmark it.

**Contstraints**

The idea is that everything is done on one view with a persistent google map however there are certain states that are saved within that view.

**Conclusion**

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Okay after some more research I think I have the answer.

According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377676/multiple-layers-of-deep-linking-in-angularjs?rq=1 You can set variables by the URL. And for each route I make I would just use the same partial. It seems so obvious now. Learning angular has been one of the hardest things I have tried to learn.

Sorry for posting a question that was already answered in another thread. I was searching and searching and nothing relevat was coming up. It was only after I made the post that a relevant question popped up in the side bar.